# Why isn't my bootstrap navbar-toggler button working?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

So I have my navbar and I made it so that in a large screen it shows the items in the navabar, but in a small screen a button shows up so you can click it to toggle the items in the navbar. It serves it's purpose in the large screen, however when it comes to the small screen, it shows the button but it does nothing when I click it. Am I missing something? Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-ms fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Homepage</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't include the required JavaScript files

Comment: @j08691 what would those files be? Like, I've I read something that said, "You can make bootstrap navbar hide/show for mobile devices without using javascript.
" can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following meta tag in head section

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

please add following code before closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added that code and now it works, thank you!

Comment: good to know that it solved your issue. please see edited answer...

Comment: yes... for mobile devices, this meta tag needed for responsiveness

Comment: have a look for more details at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/